# How to update a table column with data from a sub query that fetches duplicate records

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `abc` which has certain user data (name, ID, date of joining) another table `xyz` has similar columns but has duplicate data. I want to update date column of table `abc` with the date value of `xyz`. But `xyz` has duplicate data and giving error 'single row subquery returns...'. How do I update data from one table to another when another table has duplicate data. I want to retain the data in table `xyz` as is and cannot delete duplicate records. The query that I am using is:-

```
update abc
set date = (select date from 
( select a.date from xyz a, abc b where a.emp_id=b.emp_id ))-- this query gives duplicate records hence the error single row subquery...

where exists
( select 1 from ( select a.emp_id from abc a, xyz b where a.emp_id=b.emp_id)
)
```

Comment: Do the duplicate rows have the same date values, or are they different; and if they're different, how would you want to pick which one to use? More importantly, as shown you aren't correlating the update - there's no link between the row you're updating and the data being queried, since you join to `abc` again in the subquery. That will give you your error even if there aren't actually any duplicates. So is this what your query really looks like?

Comment: Are you really looking for an `UPDATE` -- or rather for an `INSERT` or a [`MERGE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) ? Will the newly imported values override the old ones ? Maybe some sample input data and the expected outcome might help to clearly understand your needs ?

Answer (score 0):

If your subquery returns same date for all the records it can be modified as below

```
 select a.date from xyz a, abc b where a.emp_id=b.emp_id and rownum = 1
```

Comment: But that still gives you a single (random, since there's no ordering) value from the join of the two tables for all IDs; every row in `abc` would be updated with the same date, which will not be relevant to most of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try using max or min to get one of the duplicated values.

```
update abc b
set date = (select max(date) from 
xyz a where a.emp_id=b.emp_id )
```